# C# как управлять другими приложениями с помощью своего?

Tags: c#, c++

Например если нужно нажимать на определенную кнопку в каком-нибудь постороннем приложении/браузере, или скажем добавить кого-то в друзья в дискорде, поставить громкость в плеере на 30% и т.п.
Какие неймспейсы/библиотеки/технологии нужно использовать чтобы получить методы управления другими приложениями с помощью кода C#? Или как вообще можно создавать такие приложения?

P.s.
Если это затруднительно/сложно/невозможно с помощью C#, то как решить эту задачу с помощью C++?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Comment: Единственное, что сложно и затруднительно сделать на C# - это писать низкоуровневые драйверы или компоненты ядра операционной системы, либо писать в окружении, в котором невозможен запуск CLR+JIT. Но в таких местах обычно пишут на C, а не на C++. А Win API в C# так же легко использовать как и в C++, и P/Invoke `[DllImport]` вам поможет. COM в C# тоже доступен без ограничений. Так что пишите на том, что больше нравится.

Comment: Посмотрите на эту [книжечку](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2090-4.html)...